# Reusing Memory, When is it worth?

Tags: c++11, memory-management

So to start off just to set it as an example:

I want to work with a sparse, compressed data. I know of the term "less data is faster". I do it both for performance and memory compression, however thats not really the question.

Since compresssed data is often varies in size (in terms of arrays), i wanted to reuse the arrays that no longer are active. I sort of wanted to sort them by "Size" in a linked list or something.

But then again. Some arrays might be as small as 16 bytes. and some might be over 1mb. Since adding to many items into the linked list would make it not worth at all, its just faster to create a new one.

*So my question is what size of an array should be the minimum for it to concider worth to be reused?*

Since this is for a voxel-based data, I know already that fixed size memory is faster to proccess, and easier to reuse(since they are the same size basically), i dont really want to switch methods.

Just some numbers that maybe has some worth?:
The chunk sizes variates depending on its "complexity". which basically is the size of the array.
The amount of complexity varies alot. from 4 bytes to even 100kb.
The chunks lifetime is 5 s to 5 min.

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is what size of an array should be the minimum for it to concider worth to be reused?

It will depend on many factors of your system, most likely no one can tell you in general terms.

The best way to find out is to make a parameter in your program that sets some threshold, then measure the performance with various settings of this.